# Django syncdb, Error: One or more models did not validate

Tags: django, django-south

Good greetings Django's.

I'm a newbie, and while trying to make sure the database is synced, I get `Error: One or more models did not validate`.

Any ideas how I can fix it?

```
./manage.py syncdb --settings=settings.jacob
Error: One or more models did not validate:
users.userprofile: "uuid": Primary key fields cannot have null=True.
places.category: "uuid": Primary key fields cannot have null=True.
places.image: "uuid": Primary key fields cannot have null=True.
places.masterplace: "uuid": Primary key fields cannot have null=True.
places.place: "uuid": Primary key fields cannot have null=True.

./manage.py schemamigration appname --auto --settings=settings.jacob
Error: One or more models did not validate:
users.userprofile: "uuid": Primary key fields cannot have null=True.
places.category: "uuid": Primary key fields cannot have null=True.
places.image: "uuid": Primary key fields cannot have null=True.
places.masterplace: "uuid": Primary key fields cannot have null=True.
places.place: "uuid": Primary key fields cannot have null=True.
```

Comment: Can you post some of your models.

Comment: done, and now I do see null=False but unsure why it's there and if that's the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is `django-uuidfield==0.4` in requirements.txt

or https://stackoverflow.com/a/13859974/194515