# syncdb = Error: One or more models did not validate

Tags: django, uuid, django-south

When I do `manage.py syncdb` I get:

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
users.userprofile: "uuid": Primary key fields cannot have null=True.
```

even though my `class UserProfile(models.Model)` have:

```
uuid = UUIDField(primary_key=True, auto=True, editable=False)
```

Comment: Where is UUIDField coming from? Does it perhaps default to `null=True`? If so, can you override it in your declaration by specifically setting `null=False`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) was probably it, I just didn't know how to follow the clue.

The fix, that came from [Joshua](https://stackoverflow.com/users/846313/joshua-karjala-svendsen), was to remove the official `django-uuidfield`'s and replace them with Joshua's [fork](https://github.com/joshuakarjala/django-uuidfield).

```
-django-uuidfield==0.4
-django-uuidfield-2==0.6.5
+# django-uuidfield==0.4
+# django-uuidfield-2==0.6.5
+-e git://github.com/joshuakarjala/django-uuidfield.git#egg=django-uuidfield
```

Remember to `pip uninstall django-uuidfield` and `pip uninstall django-uuidfield-2` before `pip install -r requirements.txt`.